# Check if number is too large or not a number

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a string safely,

```
public <T> long safeParseLong(T s){
    try {
        return Long.parseLong(s.toString());
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This will always work and if the string is not parsable, it will return 0.

However, is there a way to know what the reason is for it to be unparsable? Specifically, I want to know if it is not a number at all (`"foo"`) or the number is too large (≥ 9223372036854775808).

Comment: A naive approach is to use a regex and check if it's number-like but has too many digits.

Comment: I don't like this "safe" method. What happens is s = "0" for example? How do you know if it was an error or that was the actual value? And s = null?

Comment: Parse it into a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String- and do the check manually before calling `longValue()`.

Comment: @m0skit0 A flag will be raised somewhere else if it throws an exception, but I don't think that matters in this question.

Comment: @Marco13 Good idea. No need to check manually. Parse to BigInteger then parse to Long. If the first parsing throws and exception, it is not a valid number. If the second parsing throws an exception, it is too big.

Comment: Guava's `Longs.tryParse` would also do what you're looking for effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Long.parseLong` method will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the string isn't a number or if the number wouldn't fit in a `long`.

If the exception is thrown, then test whether the string fits the regular expression for a number, `"[+-]?[0-9]+"`.  If it matches, it's a number that couldn't fit in a `long`.  If it doesn't match, then it wasn't a number at all, e.g. `"foo"`.

```
boolean isNumber = s.toString().matches("[+-]?[0-9]+");
```

But you are returning `0` if there was an error.  This is indistinguishable from if the content of the string were `"0"`.  Perhaps it would be better to let an exception be thrown from this method.  But instead of a `NumberFormatException`, you could create and throw a `NotANumberException` if it's not a numeric string, or a `NumberMagnitudeTooLargeException` if the parsing failed because it's too large to fit in a `long`.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Long.parseLong will throw NumberFormatException in any case.

```
Long.parseLong(new String(new BigInteger(Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE)).add(new BigInteger("1")).toString()));
```

results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9223372036854775808"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```